# How to remove files using File widget

Tags: 7, entities, files

After clicking on the "Remove" button, the entry disappears, but the file is still on the server.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed files are deleted on cron run for D7.

Comment: I think this is the first time I've ever upvoted an answer with less than 10 words. Nicely done :)